# Google contacts API returns corrupted data

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api

this question is for Google API team which is supposedly monitoring this forum.

We're seeing cases where the contacts API is sending us data that is quite different from what a user of that account sees in web interface. For some entries Name() is absent although it's visible to the user in Gmail and for other entries Organizations() are empty although a company name is visible to the user in Gmail.

Could someone please look into this? This seems like a major API issue.

We simply do this and the returned entry looks wrong:
ContactEntry entry = myService.getEntry(entryUrl, ContactEntry.class);

Thank you,
Alexey

Comment: I am happy to provide the mailbox and contact id details. -A

Answer (score 0):

This would need to be looked at in details to be sure but as far as I know the Contacts API only returns data entered manually/private contacts data of the user whereas the Contacts UI in Gmail might merge these private data from the Public Google+ profile of users and can also merge Company-wide data (Google Apps Profiles). This might explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Hi Nivco, Thank you for the response. I can provide exact contact id, by email. Would you be able to verify the record? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Google, we're running into this situation again for another user. API does not return a name whereas the user can see the name in his Gmail interface. I can provide contact id privately. Could someone be able to look into this?